# Pycharm doesn't recognize ttf (format for fonts)

Tags: pycharm

[Is it possible to do something with this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6pRf.png)

I tried to install a program that can read ttf(FontForge). Outside of pycharm, everything works, I can open the font file, but it still does not recognize it in pycharm.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Change the font of pycharm or be able to display ttf in pycharm? You can configure file extensions as shown here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-registering-file-types.html

Comment: In addition: do not put links to external pictures. I'll not open it, and you didn't describe what you want. -- Google fonts have various tools (in python, and I used them with PyCharm) to work with ttf files.